# How to enter integers to a textfield and add them to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, java.util.scanner, jtextfield

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent BUTTON_PRESS) { 

    if(BUTTON_PRESS.getSource() == button){                        

            /* Would like to use the TextField input as a Scanner here */

            outputField.setText(output);
        }
    }
```

I wish to take user input and use the "ints" to perform calculations such as mean , avg etc.

Is this possible ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to add ints into an array:

Your code sets the text from the JTextField, and this seems the opposite of what you wish to do. Instead get the text from the JTextField via `getText()`, convert it to an int via `Integer.parseInt(...)`, and then put it into your array.

Something like:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
   String text = myTextField.getText();
   int myInt = Integer.parseInt(text); // better to surround with try/catch
   myArray[counter] = myInt;
   counter++; // to move to the next counter
}
```

If you're trying to do numeric calculations, then there is no need for an array, and your question would be very confusing.

---

**Edit**
Regarding your comment:

> So i cant split a string of numbers from a text field and say add them together ?

You could use a Scanner object to parse it:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
   String text = myTextField.getText();
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
   // to add:
   int sum = 0;
   while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
      sum += scanner.nextInt();
   }
   scanner.close();
   outputField.setText("Sum: " + sum);
}
```

or...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
   List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   String text = myTextField.getText();
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
   // to add to a list
   while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
      list.add(scanner.nextInt());
   }
   scanner.close();

   // now you can iterate through the list to do all sorts of math operations
   // outputField.setText();
}
```

Comment: So i cant split a string of numbers from a text field and say add them together ?

Comment: No,unless you perform a kind of splitting using some regex techniques!

Comment: @Aaron: you could also use a Scanner object to parse the input. Please see edit to answer

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels you've been too kind